# error parsing data org.json.exeception

Tags: android

here is my doInbackground code from a class that extends Asynctask

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_EMAIL, emailMember));

        JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_pembayaran, "POST", paramss);

        Log.d("shopping chart", json.toString());
        return json.toString();
    }
```

actually in always work at another code
this is my oncreate code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bayar);

    txt_total_harga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_total_harga);
    txt_ongkos_kirim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_ongkos_kirim);
    txt_jumlah_barang = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_jumlah_barang);
    txt_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_status);

    btnBayar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBayarSemua);

    Intent ambil = getIntent();
    idChart = ambil.getStringExtra("idShopping");

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("login", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    emailMember = prefs.getString("emailMember", "");

    new DetailSC().execute();
}
```

this is my class that extends to Asynctask

```
class DetailSC extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> paramss = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        paramss.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_EMAIL, emailMember));

        JSONObject json = parser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_pembayaran, "POST", paramss);

        Log.d("shopping chart", json.toString());
        return json.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
        try{
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if(success == 1){

                shopping_detail = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOPPING);
                JSONObject jObject = shopping_detail.getJSONObject(0);

                int totalHarga = jObject.getInt(TAG_TOTAL_HARGA);
                int berat = json.getInt(TAG_BERAT);
                String ongkos = json.getString(TAG_ONGKOS_KIRIM);
                int ongkosK = Integer.parseInt(ongkos);
                totalHarga = ( berat * ongkosK ) / 1000;

                txt_jumlah_barang.setText(jObject.getString(TAG_JUMLAH_BARANG));
                txt_ongkos_kirim.setText(ongkos);
                txt_status.setText(jObject.getString(TAG_STATUS));
                txt_total_harga.setText("IDR " + totalHarga);
            }
        }catch(JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Bayar.this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading Data . . .");
        pDialog.show();
    }

}
```

the error in logcat is :
eror parsing data org.json.JSONException : value email of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: can you share json response

Comment: no hehe, i've just repaired it, the problem's at my json response

Comment: So problem is solved . Good enjoy :)